# Add Target Window/Tab to Tablix Action URL

Tags: ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

Using SQL Server 2012 Report Builder 3.0, I have the following URL defined in my query, to launch the applicable record in SAP from the report.

```
CASE WHEN DM_IAM_D_I_ROOT.APPLICATION = 'MOC' 
    THEN concat('http://sapep2di05.erp.xxxxxxxx.com:8000/nwbc/~canvas;window=app/wda/MOC/WDA_CHANGE_REQUEST/?CHANGE_MODE=&SAP-WD-CONFIGID=%2fMOC%2fWDA_CHANGE_REQUEST&SAP-LANGUAGE=EN&KEY=', convert(nvarchar(32), DM_IAM_D_I_ROOT.DB_KEY, 2), '&sap-client=100') 
    WHEN DM_IAM_D_I_ROOT.APPLICATION = 'QIM' 
    THEN concat('http://sapep2di05.erp.xxxxxxxx.com:8000/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/qim_ovp_issue?iss_appr=X&iss_cat=QIM&iss_status=09&issue_id=', DM_IAM_D_I_ROOT.ISSUE_ID, '&issue_type=CAP&processing_mode=DISPLAY') END as ISSURL
```

Then I just add it as the "Action URL" to a field in the tablix to make it a clickable link.

[image: Text Box Properties - Action - Go to URL]

This works great, except that some browsers (Edge/Chrome) are taking over the report tab to launch the link.  I can't figure out the syntax for how to add the 'target="_blank"' expression to the end of the URL, since the URL expression in my SQL query doesn't include the entirely hyperlink syntax, only the target URL itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a bit of javascript in your link.

Try changing your expression to something like

```
="javascript:void(window.open('" & TRIM(Fields!ISSURL.Value) & "','_blank'))"
```

This will launch a new window.

Comment: Nailed it!  Thanks!